# resolve property conflicts in svn

Tags: svn, version-control, conflict

I saw this line from the free svn online book:

> "To resolve property conflicts, simply
>   ensure that the conflicting properties
>   contain the values that they should,
>   and then use the svn resolved command
>   to alert Subversion that you have
>   manually resolved the problem."

I had a conflict in my repo with the svn:ignore property. I fixed the conflicts as was said in the .prej file generated by the conflict

How do I tell SVN that the conflict with the property is now resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it. I examined the contents of `dir_conflicts.prej` which will give me an idea of the conflict. I then fixed it as specified in the file and I deleted `dir_conflicts.prej` and the conflict was already resolved.

Comment: With this method, `svn info` still shows the conflicted state. khmarbaise's answer fixes this; maybe deleting it is enough to automagically resolve itself when you commit?

Answer (score 11):

You have to given the resolved command.

```
svn resolved .
```

"." for the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is late but It will help others

TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 provide a simple solution.

> - Go to the folder where `dir_conflicts.prej` file is present.
> - Right click (don't select anything to right click).
> - Select TortoiseSVN > Edit Conflict
> - Tool will open a dialog box
>
>   - select edit conflict
>   - make changes and mark as resolved